# Generate structures on a Minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I set up generate-structures=false in server.properties before creating a world. But villages still exist!

How to fix it?

Comment: Please be for specific. For example, do you have any mods added on?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a mod installed, this may be causing the villages to spawn. Try removing one mod at a time and see when the villages go away. Add all the mods back apart from the one you removed last.

If you don't have a mod installed, you should try deleting the world and then running the server. This is because if the world is already generated, setting `generate-structures=false` will not remove the villages.